# How to use a function containing if-else structure to every column using R

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, apply, lapply

The data frame sg is as follwoing:

```
 v1 v2 v3 
 A  B  C  
 B  A  B  
 C  A  A
```

I used a function

```
definition <- funciton(x){
  if (x =='A') definition <- paste(x, ": MINIMUM_RED")   
  else if (x =='B') definition <- paste(x, ": PASSIVE_RED")   ## Passive red (no green demand during red)
  else if (x =='C') definition <- paste(x, ": RED_REQUEST")   ## During red the group has a green demand
  else if (x =='D') definition <- paste(x, ": RED_PRIORITY")  
  else if (x =='E') definition <- paste(x, ": RED_PRIVILEGE")  ## During red possilbe to go green
  else  definition <- paste(x, ": RED_WAIT")   ## 
}
```

I want to use the function definition for every value in the data frame sg, so I used apply function:

```
sgdf <- apply(sg,2,defination)
```

The result is as following:

```
     [,1]              [,2]              [,3]             
[1,] "A : MINIMUM_RED" "B : PASSIVE_RED" "C : RED_REQUEST"
[2,] "B : MINIMUM_RED" "A : PASSIVE_RED" "B : RED_REQUEST"
[3,] "C : MINIMUM_RED" "A : PASSIVE_RED" "A : RED_REQUEST"
```

Obviously, the function only works on the first element in every column, is any way I can get the right definition of every value?

Comment: I am reminded of some wags' comment that you can write FORTRAN code in any language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may just use a list to map each character to a definition.

For instance

```
sg <- data.frame(v1=c("A", "B", "C"),
                 v2=c("B", "A", "A"),
                 v3=c("C", "A", "A")) 

defs <- list("A" = "MINIMUM_RED",
         "B" = "PASSIVE_RED",
         "C" = "RED_REQUEST",
         "D" = "RED_PRIORITY",
         "E" = "RED_PRIVILEGE")

# Convert the data frame in a matrix, so we can use it to index the list
tmp <- as.matrix(sg)

# note that paste works on vectors
res <- matrix(paste(tmp, defs[tmp]), ncol=ncol(tmp))
```

Resulting in:

```
     [,1]            [,2]            [,3]           
[1,] "A MINIMUM_RED" "B PASSIVE_RED" "C RED_REQUEST"
[2,] "B PASSIVE_RED" "A MINIMUM_RED" "A MINIMUM_RED"
[3,] "C RED_REQUEST" "A MINIMUM_RED" "A MINIMUM_RED"
```

Comment: Yours and zx8754 look like what i would call "vectorized". I don't think the other ones with nested `ifelse`'s will perform as well on larger data.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the vectorized `ifelse` in your function definition instead of `if` and `else` or use `gsub` instead.

**edit** The following is the vectorized version for illustration, but I think the alterative answers by lookup are a much better solution. But this does illustrate that `ifelse` is vectorized while `if` is not.

```
definition <- function (x) {
  y <-
    ifelse(x =='A', "MINIMUM_RED",
           ifelse(x =='B', "PASSIVE_RED",
                  ifelse(x =='C', "RED_REQUEST", 
                         ifelse(x =='D', "RED_PRIORITY",
                                ifelse(x =='E', "RED_PRIVILEGE",  
                                       "RED_WAIT")))))
  return(paste(x, ":", y))
}


x <- LETTERS[1:5]
definition(x)
#[1] "A : MINIMUM_RED"   "B : PASSIVE_RED"   "C : RED_REQUEST"   "D : RED_PRIORITY" 
#[5] "E : RED_PRIVILEGE"
```

Comment: You may want to expand this answer with an example of code. Although I would generally agree that `ifelse` is a good way of doing this, an `ifelse` with 5 cases may not be the prettiest piece of code...

Comment: @nico I agree completely, but it's easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Using lookup variables:

```
#dummy data
df <- read.table(text="v1 v2 v3 
A  B  C  
B  A  B  
C  A  A  ", header=TRUE)

#make lookup variables
ind <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
def <- paste0(ind,":",
              c("MINIMUM_RED",
                "PASSIVE_RED",
                "RED_REQUEST",
                "RED_PRIORITY",
                "RED_PRIVILEGE"))
#result         
sapply(df,function(i){def[order(i)]})

#output
# v1              v2              v3             
# [1,] "A:MINIMUM_RED" "B:PASSIVE_RED" "C:RED_REQUEST"
# [2,] "B:PASSIVE_RED" "C:RED_REQUEST" "B:PASSIVE_RED"
# [3,] "C:RED_REQUEST" "A:MINIMUM_RED" "A:MINIMUM_RED"
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some better suggested solutions, but if you want to change your current code as little as possible, just adding a `sapply` in your last line should work:

```
sgdf <- apply(sg, 2, sapply, definition)
```

Another possibility is to use `match` with `nomatch=6` as an indicator variable. This has the advantage over some of the suggestions that it also works for matrix entries that are not in A-E, i.e. the case of `paste(x, ": RED_WAIT")`.

```
newvals <- c(": MINIMUM_RED",  ": PASSIVE_RED", ": RED_REQUEST",
             ": RED_PRIORITY", ": RED_PRIVILEGE", ": RED_WAIT")
ind <- match(as.matrix(sg), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), nomatch=6)
matrix(paste(as.matrix(sg), newvals[ind]), ncol = ncol(sg))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a `switch` statement? They're nice and clean, and `switch` is a `.Primitive`

```
definition <- function(data)
{
    m <- as.matrix(data)
    for(i in seq_along(m)){
        if(m[i] %in% LETTERS[1:5]){
            m[i] <- switch(m[i], 
                   A = paste(m[i], ": MINIMUM_RED"),
                   B = paste(m[i], ": PASSIVE_RED"),
                   C = paste(m[i], ": RED_REQUEST"),
                   D = paste(m[i], ": RED_PRIORITY"),
                   E = paste(m[i], ": RED_PRIVILEGE")
                   )
        } else {
            m[i] =  paste(m[i], ": RED_WAIT") 
        }
    }
    return(m)
}
```

The resulting matrix is

```
definition(dat)
#      v1                v2                v3               
# [1,] "A : MINIMUM_RED" "B : PASSIVE_RED" "C : RED_REQUEST"
# [2,] "B : PASSIVE_RED" "A : MINIMUM_RED" "B : PASSIVE_RED"
# [3,] "C : RED_REQUEST" "A : MINIMUM_RED" "A : MINIMUM_RED"
```

and `dat` is

```
dat <-
structure(list(v1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    v2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
    v3 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("v1", 
"v2", "v3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

---

**Better yet, let's just vectorize it instead.**  Here's a new data frame with a few values that won't be matched

```
DF <- structure(list(v1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L),
.Label = c("A", "B", "C", "F"), class = "factor"), 
v2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "D", "E"), class = "factor"),
v3 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "G", "R"), class = "factor")),
.Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
> DF
#   v1 v2 v3
# 1  A  B  C
# 2  B  A  B
# 3  C  A  A
# 4  F  D  G
# 5  A  E  R
```

And the replacement

```
> q <- c(": MINIMUM_RED", ": PASSIVE_RED", ": RED_REQUEST", ": RED_PRIORITY", ": RED_PRIVILEGE")
YES <- paste(LETTERS[1:5], q); NO <- "NA : RED_WAIT"
> m <- as.matrix(DF)
> for(i in seq(m)){ m[i] <- q[match(m[i], LETTERS[1:5])] }
> m[is.na(m)] <- NO
> m
#      v1                v2                  v3               
# [1,] "A : MINIMUM_RED" "B : PASSIVE_RED"   "C : RED_REQUEST"
# [2,] "B : PASSIVE_RED" "A : MINIMUM_RED"   "B : PASSIVE_RED"
# [3,] "C : RED_REQUEST" "A : MINIMUM_RED"   "A : MINIMUM_RED"
# [4,] "NA : RED_WAIT"   "D : RED_PRIORITY"  "NA : RED_WAIT"  
# [5,] "A : MINIMUM_RED" "E : RED_PRIVILEGE" "NA : RED_WAIT"
```